# Trigger a full calculation in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Given a workbook that contains lots of formulas, i realise that when its cell values are up-to-date, `F9`, `ActiveWorkbook.Calculate` or `Sheets(1).calculate` does not trigger a re-calculation.

However, if a cell value that is referenced by another cell through formula changes, `F9`, `ActiveWorkbook.Calculate` or `Sheets(1).calculate` will trigger a recalculation of all the formulas that depend on the changed cell.

In one word, Excel just recalculates which is necessary.

However, I would like to measure the behavior (eg, time) of a FULL calculation of the workbook (ie, refreshing from the constant values, then the formulas depending on them, then a higher level formulas...).

Does anyone know how to trigger such a full calculation in VBA?

Comment: have a look at the 5th comment (and links) posted here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/456468-measure-time-takes-excel-calculate-formulas.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options - `CalculateFull` and `CalculateFullRebuild`. The latter will rebuild the entire dependency chain so may be overkill here. Note that both will apply to all open workbooks, not just the active one.

Comment: Will `CalculateFullRebuild` refresh external connections ?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Not as far as I know. Refresh and calculate are two separate things to Excel. Or did you mean formula links to external workbooks?

Comment: I did not mean external like.......only external connections...........thanks for the answer.