# Array formula not updating until enter is pressed again

Tags: excel, array-formulas

This question can, I guess, be part of the same problem mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56542903/7862279) that I have asked a couple of days ago.

My problem is that I have an array formula that looks in a table for cells containing `FAIL`. Basically, if there is a `FAIL` in the table, the array formula returns the line of the fail if there is none it says `No failure`.

But I also have buttons running some macros that filter the data in the same table (but do not remove the `FAIL`). When I click on the button/run the macro the macro display `No failure` which is not correct. However if I press *ctrl+shift+enter* (without changing the formula) it updates to the correct value (being the line of the `FAIL`).

So **in a nutshell** my array formula is not updating until I press *ctrl+shift+enter* a second time and i don't know why.

Refreshing the sheet, closing-opening again, or using the calculate now function do not work.

---

My formula (fairly messy I admit haha) is:

`=IF(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((Table1[Load Pass fail]="FAIL"),IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[Measure])),ROW(Table1[Load Pass fail]),""),""))="",IF($E$23="","Not run","No failure"),TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((Table1[Load Pass fail]="FAIL")*(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[Measure]))),ROW(Table1[Load Pass fail]),"")))`

---

If you can help me thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT:** it appears that when I change one of the value in the parts of the table targeted by my array formula it triggers the formula and it goes back to the correct value.

Comment: What is the order you are creating the array formula and pressing the macro button? There are these rules for changing an array formula - The last one seems to suggest that you'd have to do the ctrl+shift+enter anytime you change the underlying data. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rules-for-changing-array-formulas-8a80c2c1-44c1-42c3-88c1-37a3a7c2d367

Comment: @HungryBeagle the array formula was already created when the button was pressed. I'm not trying to edit the array formula as it is working properly (well until this problem haha)

Comment: What happens if you put the command >      Calculate      at the end of your macro? That should trigger a sheet calculation iirc?

Comment: @Jon I tried and it doesn't do anything. Even manually, refreshing the sheet, closing-opening again, or using the calculate now/calculate sheet function don't work..

Comment: Okay, it is probably because you aren't triggering a cell change affected by the formula. Without being able to see your workbook, why not have a dummy cell included in your formula with (say) the value zero, then just change it to one and back in your macro. It wouldn't affect the calculation materially, but it might trigger a recalculation. Hope it helps?

Comment: @Jon I think you are right because when the bug appears, if I change a value in the targeted parts of the table the array formula recalculates. So you are suggesting that I put something in my macros that changes the value of one cell inside the parts of the table targeted by my array formula?

Comment: Yep. You can even have your standard array formula, then at the end something like =yourarrayformula + $z$200 (ctrl+shift+enter) , then in your macro have something near the end that does cells(200,26).value = cells(200,26) + 1.  I don't know if it'll work, but it seems a good stab. Good luck.

Comment: @Jon I see. However I have just tried and the problem appears also when I filter the data manually. So unfortunately I can't use this solution in a long term view...

Comment: Hmm. Try this?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005766/trigger-a-full-calculation-in-vba    It won't solve the manual filter thing. You could also consider using the subtotal formula somewhere - this only calculates visible cells so would change as you filtered. You could have it trigger an event maybe.

Comment: @Jon I think even the functions stated in the link don't work (or I am not using them properly but if it is the case I will sort this out). However I thank you as I understand a little bit better the problem and potential ways to solve it. I will dig a little deeper into the triggering the formula and post the solution if I find it!

Comment: Don't use the formulas - use the VBA calls in the answer :) - i.e. calculatefull and calculatefullrebuild.